# Accounting for number of matches while comparing

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement in PySpark as follows

1. Compare table1 and table2 on the key field "accountid" (Consider only the recods where flg == 'new')
2. Once a match is found on the key column, then compare the remaining
   non-key columns
3. While comparing the non-key columns, if there are matches in **3** or
   more fields we change the value of the flg field to 'ready'.
4. However, while comparing the non-key columns, if there is mismatch
   in more than **2** columns, change the value of the flg to 'wip'

Dataset 1:

```
agency | advertiser | account_type | advertiserid | accountid | status | flag
CMC    | APAC       | OPEN         | 700012       | 900034    | A      | 'new'
BMC    | EU         | ACTIVE       | 700031       | 839910    | B      | 'rec'
TTU    | APAC       | OPEN         | 700128       | 691230    | B      | 'new'
CPR    | JPN        | ACTIVE       | 701234       | 320021    | A      | 'new'
```

Dataset 2:

```
agency | advertiser | account_type | advertiserid | accountid | status
CMC    | PANAM      | OPEN         | 700012       | 900034    | A 
BMC    | EU         | ACTIVE       | 700031       | 839910    | B 
CPR    | EU         | OPEN         | 700128       | 691230    | B 
ANZ    | BRZ        | CLOSED       | 701234       | 320021    | A
```

Output :

```
agency | advertiser | account_type | advertiserid | accountid | status | flg
CMC    | PANAM      | OPEN         | 700012       | 900034    | A      | 'ready'
BMC    | EU         | ACTIVE       | 700031       | 839910    | B      | 'rec'
CPR    | EU         | OPEN         | 700128       | 691230    | B      | 'ready'
CPR    | JPN        | ACTIVE       | 701234       | 320021    | A      | 'wip'
```

- The final record is 'wip' because there are mismatches in more than 2
  columns. Hence flg = 'wip'.
- Record-2 is untouched since flg = 'rec'
- Record-1 and Record-2 have have 3 or more than 3 column matches,
  hence flg = 'ready'

I tried with `LeftOuter` Join, but can't seem to handle the number of column matches into consideration. I need to do this in PySpark DataFrame API or spark.sql(""")
Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL, I'd try doing all the comparisons in a derived table. Then in the outer query you can derive your flg column.

Something like this:

```
select
dataset.*,
case 
  when flag = 'rec' then 'rec
  when tst1 + tst2 + ... >= 3 then 'ready'
  else 'wip'
end as flg
from
(
select
dataset1.*,
case when dataset1.agency = dataset2.agency  then 1 end as tst1,
case when dataset1.advertiser = dataset2.advertiser  then 1 end as tst2
...
from
dataset1
left join dataset2  -- don't know if you need an outer join here
  on dataset1.accountid = dataset2.accountid
) dataset
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array for the columns that you want to compare and use `array_intersect` and `size` to derive your flag.

With Pyspark API

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = ['agency', 'advertiser','account_type', 'advertiserid', 'status']

df1 = df1.withColumn('arr1', F.array(*cols))
df2 = df2.withColumn('arr2', F.array(*cols))

df = (df1.join(df2.select('accountid', 'arr2'), on='accountid', how='left')
      .withColumn('flag', (F.when(F.col('flag') == 'rec', F.col('flag'))
                           .when(F.size(F.array_intersect('arr1', 'arr2')) >= 3, 'ready')
                           .otherwise('wip')))
      .drop('arr1', 'arr2'))
```

With SQL

```
cols = ['agency', 'advertiser','account_type', 'advertiserid', 'status']

df = spark.sql(f"""
    select {','.join('df.'+x for x in cols)},
        case
            when df.flag = 'rec' then 'rec'
            when 3 <= size(array_intersect(df.arr1, df.arr2)) then 'ready' 
            else 'wip'
        end as flag
    from (select df1.*,
              array({','.join('df1.'+x for x in cols)}) as arr1,
              array({','.join('df2.'+x for x in cols)}) as arr2 
          from df1 
          left join df2 on df1.accountid = df2.accountid) df
""")
```